# Removing NaN rows from a three dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I remove the `NaN` rows from the array below using indices (since I will need to remove the same rows from a different array.

```
array([[[nan,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0., nan,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

I get the indices of the rows to be removed by using the command

```
a[np.isnan(a).any(axis=2)]
```

But using what I would normally use on a 2D array does not produce the desired result, losing the array structure.

```
a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=2)]
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How can I remove the rows I want using the indices obtained from my first command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape:

```
a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=2)].reshape(a.shape[0], -1, a.shape[2])
```

But be aware that the number of NaN-rows at each 2D subarray should be the same to get a new 3D array.

Comment: There is no guarantee that they will be

Comment: @dearn44 then you cannot get a 3D array. The shape[1] should be fixed.

Comment: @dearn44 NumPy does not support jagged arrays natively.

Comment: makes sense, I will accept this answer given that it solves the issue in question under logical constraints